# About Site URL in Web part

Tags: web-part

I have some webparts. All of them has a property to enter the Site URL i.e the URL where the deployment should happen. My server farm contains, multiple zones with different URLs. In order to deploy each webpart I should change  the Site URL for each zone before I actually build the application. Could you please let me know an easy way where I can deploy the application once for all the different URLs of webparts?

The same Site URL is taken as webapp URL when deploying the application using Powershell.

```
function DeployWsp([string]$solutionName, [string[]]$webApplicationList, [bool]$redeploy = $true) {

    $solution = Get-SPSolution $solutionName -ea SilentlyContinue

    # Remove the existing solution if it already exists
    if($solution -ne $null -and $redeploy -eq $true)
    {       
        Write-Host "Solution $solutionName already exists... Removing." -nonewline
        if ($solution.ContainsWebApplicationResource) {
            $solution | Uninstall-SPSolution -AllWebApplications -Confirm:$false
        } else {
            $solution | Uninstall-SPSolution -Confirm:$false
        }       
        while ( $solution.JobExists ){
            write-host "." -nonewline
            sleep 2
        }
        Remove-SPSolution -Identity $solutionName -Confirm:$false
        while ( $solution.JobExists ){
            write-host "." -nonewline
            sleep 2
        }
        Write-Host " Done."
    }

    if ($solution -eq $null -or !$solution.Deployed )
    { 
        Write-Host "Deploying the $solutionName solution" -nonewline    
        $solution = Add-SPSolution "$pwd\$solutionName"

        for ($i=0; $i -lt $webApplicationList.length; $i++)
        {
            $webApplication = $webApplicationList[$i]

            if ($solution.ContainsWebApplicationResource) {
                Write-Host " to $webApplication." -nonewline    
                Install-SPSolution $solutionName -WebApplication $webApplication -GACDeployment:$($solution.ContainsGlobalAssembly) -CASPolicies:$($solution.ContainsCasPolicy) -force
            } else {
                Install-SPSolution $solutionName -GACDeployment:$($solution.ContainsGlobalAssembly) -CASPolicies:$($solution.ContainsCasPolicy) -force
            }
            do {
                Start-Sleep 5
                Write-Host "." -nonewline
            } while ($solution.JobExists)

            Write-Host " Done."
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you should care about isn't the AAM zones, but the web application default zone. think it would be best to take the .wsp from the package and deploy it to each of the web applications using this Powershell command:

```
Add-SPSolution "C:\webpart.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity webpart.wsp –AllWebApplications –GACDeployment
```

This will take care of deploying the wsp out to all the webapplications in the farm. You of course have to enable the feature after you deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it does helpful. But, when building the web part application, I should mentioned the Site URL in the property of the web part solution. Otherwise, I am unable to build the webpart solution in VS.NET 2010. Could you please suggest me the best way to deal with this?I want my webpart should be of Web application independent without any broken links in it.

Comment: More ever, I got all the abosolute URL's in my Web part application, I should convert them to relative URL's please advice.

Comment: You don't need to specify the site url in the webpart solution. That will hardcode the site URL and leave you with a solution that isn't dynamic. Can you post your code that uses the Site URL?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have been struggling to fix this problem for the past one week. I got two solutions one for intranet and other is for branding. The following is the code (code behind for one of the control) for one of the webpart.

Comment: public string SiteURL { get; set; } protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            // Check properties
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteURL) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
            {
                (this.Parent as WebPart).Hidden = true;
                return;
            }

Comment: NewsHelper helper = new NewsHelper();
List<NewsItem> newsList = new List<NewsItem>();            
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL))            
{
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())                
      {
              SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(ListName);
                if (list != null)
newsList = helper.GetLatestAnnouncements(list, (uint)NumberOfAnnouncements, ContentType);}}

Comment: Sorry I have to give you the code which is not formatted due to this website's form validations.

Comment: You can delete your comments and edit your question to put the code in there. That is usually the best way to show your code.

Instead of opening the Site with  `using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL)` use `using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Web.Site)` That way your solution isn't specific to ONE web application and you can deploy it anywhere that the solution is getting it's request from.

Comment: but in VS.NET I am unable to build the application without giving the siteURL in the solution properties. Also, This is having the absolute URL instead of Relative URL.

Comment: That is the siteURL in the solution properties on the solution, not in the code. The specification of the siteURL in the solution properties is purely for deployment and debugging.

Comment: is there any way how can I by pass that as I unable to debug my solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you need some more tutorials on how debugging and web parts VS sharepoint solution work. Here is something to help you get started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513148.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will go through with the tutorial and modify my environement as per the guidance of the tutorial.